# OFBiz Accounting Application

Tags: ofbiz

How to integrate the PARTYMGR application with ACCOUNTINGMGR application.So than the services of the later one will be made available for the PARTYMGR.

Answer (score 0):

All components are already integrated. Meaning that services of any component can be used system wide, so in any other other component. If you have further questions let us know.
Our company Antwebsystems does ONLY ofbiz and interfaces to other systems.

Comment: Actually I want to add Party Transaction functionality in PARTYMGR very similar to Financial Account in ACCOUNTMGR module.Is it possible to make transactions against a partyID,similar to the transactions made against a finAccountId.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are looking for is a new screen in party manager to display party transactions but not a service.

It is easily doable in OFBiz: you have to add a new screen to list transactions (the same way as in fin account transactions) and filter them by partyId.